# audit-argument-checks and Subscriptions in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, audit

When doing checks with the `audit-argument-checks` package, how should you do the matching when checking a `Meteor.userId()`? Does the userId needs to be really checked?

```
Meteor.publish('scores', function(userId) {
    check(userId, Match.any)
    return Scores.find({userId: userId})
})
```

Comment: well, `audit-argument-checks` is dumb and requires every argument from the `arguments` list to be checked. It is not aware of special symbols or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Since ID generation for the built in users collection is always `'STRING'` and cannot be altered, you can do:

```
check(userId, String);
```

If you are using `'MONGO'` ID generation for other collections, you'll want to do:

```
check(docId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
```

Comment: The built-in users collection can only take String ID's and if ObjectID is used, the users cannot login since setUserId method expects the type to be a String. Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1834), although rejected by developers for any mitigation. So, you can safely assume it is a String.

Answer (score 3):

If the user is logged in, the publish function will already have the userId.  It is accessible with `this.userId` so no need for the user to pass it or to check it.

Like this:

```
Meteor.publish('scores', function() {
  return Scores.find({userId: this.userId})
});
```